# Adding char as many times as a number

Tags: java, string, char

So I need to make a program that has the user input a height and output the following shape with nested loops:

```
        *
      * * *
    * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
```

---

---

My idea to get this to work is to use a char as a black space and correspond that to how many spaces I need for the right shape when given the height. However, I am having trouble calling upon it. How do I make the char, run on the same line a certain number of times. I want it to correspond with my 'x' value in the second loop.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TrueArt 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int height;
    char star = '*';


    // Gets preferred height 
    System.out.println("Enter the height you want the masterpiece to be: ");
    height = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i=0; height > i; i--)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < height; i++)
        {
            1 + x * 2
        }
    }
}

}
```

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Is your above code meant to be pseudocode? your mathematical statement in the inner for loop is incorrect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047583/printing-s-as-triangles-in-java

Comment: You have an infinite loop for input heights that are greater than 0. for (int i=0; height > i; i--)

Comment: Yes, the code above was just me thinking about what I should do, it is not at all complete.

Comment: Are you allowed to use recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the output you want you can use this pyramid algorithm.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int height = s.nextInt();
char star = '*';

 for(int i = 0;i < height; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < height - i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for(int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
        System.out.print(star + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();  
}

}
```

You will have to change this a bit to get the specific shape/style pyramid you want but this is something to work off of for learning purpose.

Comment: Okay, so with your help, I got it to work. Just to make sure I understand what's going on here: a user enters in a value. Then that value goes into a loop, where it will run the number the user entered. Then inside the second loop,  it finds out how many spaces to put out by subtracting the i from height. In the last loop it prints the correct amount of stars. This makes sense when looking at it. Thanks for everyone's comments and answers.

Comment: @ChargePositive Exactly! I'm glad you got it to work! Taking programs like this one step at a time and analyzing what is and what needs to happen is essential, especially then there're lots of loops!

Answer (score 0):

Your `for loop` has infinite loop issues. Try to avoid that.

By the way, another pyramid algorithm. Cheers!

```
for (int i=height; i > 0; i--)
{
    if(i!=1) {
        for(int y = i-1; y>0; y--) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 2*(height-i+1)-1; x++)
    {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```