# Printing star and character triangle in java

Tags: java, loops

[Here is a screenshot of my Output and the desired output is located below as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDktD.png)I have to create program that outputs a star and the letter o. I have gotten it working for the most part but the output is not 100% correct, minor things really. Here is my code so far:

```
for(int i = 1; i <=numRows; i++){
    System.out.print("\n");
    for(int j = 0; j<=numRows; j++){
        if(i+j >= numRows){
            System.out.print('*');
            System.out.print("o");
        }else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
```

And here is a screenshot of what the output is supposed to look like

[image: Screenshot of the desired output]

Comment: What are those "minor things"? What problem are you having? Also, your code, as given in the question, is incomplete, in that it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Tunaki I saw this exact question asked a few days ago... no idea where to find it, though

Comment: The minor thing is that on the first row should be just a star then next row should outputting the o's

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047583/printing-s-as-triangles-in-java?rq=1 (duplicate)

Comment: Thats not the same as mine

Comment: Just looked at your photo, seems like an easy fix to me. hard code the first row to be a star, then do your loop less by one row as you already have the star.

Comment: Also, another thing I noticed, the logic here seems to make sense to me. So look at it this way; first row is hard coded as a star, that's good. Now, from there the number of o's matches the row number, so row 1 has 1 o, row 2 has 2 o's, etc. Number of inner stars is rowNum - 1; you can keep the outer stars as hard coded append values as well. Do that in a loop and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what I had to do for class a long time ago. Here is the code:

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= userInput/2; i++)
                        {
                                for(int j = 0; j < (userInput/2 - i); j++)
                                {
                                        printDiamond = printDiamond + " ";
                                }
                                for(int k = 0; k <= (i*2); k++)
                                {
                                        printDiamond = printDiamond + "*";
                                }

                                printDiamond = printDiamond + "\n";
                        }
```

**Reason it is userInput/2 is because the other half of the code prints the diamond in reverse, thus actually making a diamond and not a triangle. **

So what do we have: First inner loop is responsible for printing the white spaces that help give our diamond its shape. The next inner loop prints the top of the diamond; *2 because we want it to print the whole top of the diamond, and not just half of the diamond if we were to split it top to bottom.

I will leave the addition of the extra o's to you.