# Printing Right-Aligned Triangle by Calling Methods

Tags: java, loops, methods

Good day! Newbie in Java Programming. Would like to ask for some help on understanding the looping. The program's aim is to print a right-aligned triangle. I've created method for printing "*" and another one for " " (whitespace). I'm having trouble understanding on how can I implement the whitespace in my main method. Thank you!

Expected output:

```
"printTriangle(4);"

     *
    **
   ***
  ****
```

Here is my code:

```
public class PrintingLikeBoss {

public static void printStars(int amount) {
    int i = 1;

    while (i <= amount) {
        System.out.print("*");
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void printWhitespaces(int amount) {
    int i = 1;

    while (i <= amount) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        i++;
   }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void printTriangle(int size) {

    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        printStars(size);
        i++;
        }
    }


    printTriangle(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing \*s as triangles in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047583/printing-s-as-triangles-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The `printTriangle()` methode will never end due to `i` always being greater then 0.

Also there is no main method in your code, therefore you will not be able to run it.

Now for the answer to your question:

```
   public static void printTriangle(int size){
        int i = size;
        int j = 1;
        while(j<=i){
            printWhite(i-j);
            printStar(j);
            j++;
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void printWhite(int size){
        int i = size;
        for(int j = 0; j<i; j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    public static void printStar(int size){
        int i = size;
        for(int j = 0; j<i; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
    printTriangle(4);
    }
```

This should provide you an output like this:

```
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
```

Comment: Why are you setting i to size?

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc : Setting i to size redundant in this case, i agree, one might just as well use the variable size itself.