# I need help in Java Loops Exercise

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Hi i need help for this

Create a java program using loops that will display the following output

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

a newbie

Comment: You will need one loop to create the rows and one that creates the content of each row.

Comment: try to learn it from the basic,,, here some link for it: https://www.w3schools.com/java/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing \*s as triangles in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047583/printing-s-as-triangles-in-java) If not then search for ___java print triangle___ The question has been asked and answered several times, including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409621/creating-a-triangle-with-for-loops Plus you should also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
public class Main
{
   //main funtion 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // variable to store number of asterisks (Total asterisks)
    int asterisks = 10;
    // loop until "i" less than or equal to asterisks 
    for (int i = 0; i <= asterisks; i++) {
        //inner loop
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            //print "asterisks" until "j" less then or equal to "i".
             System.out.printf("*");
        }
        //insert newline after coming out from inner loop
        System.out.printf("\n");
     }
   }
 }
```

**Output:**

```
*                                                                                                                     
**                                                                                                                    
***                                                                                                                   
****                                                                                                                  
*****                                                                                                                 
******                                                                                                                
*******                                                                                                               
********                                                                                                              
*********                                                                                                             
**********                                                                                                            
***********
```

Comment: [Is it my duty to check for duplicate questions before answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326622/is-it-my-duty-to-check-for-duplicate-questions-before-answering)

Answer (score 0):

- (i = 1)

** (i = 2)

*** (i = 3)

```
public static void printTriangle(int length) {
    for (int i=1; i<length+1 ; i++) {
          for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
          }
          System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Is it my duty to check for duplicate questions before answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326622/is-it-my-duty-to-check-for-duplicate-questions-before-answering)

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "*";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    String toPrint = s.repeat(i + 1);
    System.out.println(toPrint);
}
```

Comment: I think you should mention that method `repeat()` was added to class `java.lang.String` in JDK 11 (eleven).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StarPattern   
{   
public static void main(String args[])   
{   
//i for rows and j for columns      
//row denotes the number of rows you want to print  
int i, j;   

for(i=1; i<=5; i++)   //outer loop  
{   

for(j=0; j<i; j++)   //inner loop
{   
//prints stars   
System.out.print("* ");   
}   
 //throws the cursor in a new line after printing each line  
 System.out.println();   
}   
}   
}
```

If you want to print more rows then, change the value of i's to your wish.

Comment: [Is it my duty to check for duplicate questions before answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326622/is-it-my-duty-to-check-for-duplicate-questions-before-answering)

Answer (score 0):

to print such a thing, you need 2 loops number one to iterate for each row and number two or inner loop to add data for each row, the number of star is related to the index of row, so we check that column be less then row:

```
for (int row = 1; row < 10; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < row; column++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: [Is it my duty to check for duplicate questions before answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326622/is-it-my-duty-to-check-for-duplicate-questions-before-answering)