# I need assistance with creating a program

Tags: java

I'm having a tough time with creating a program that will print a triangle pattern based on the number value entered by the user while using nested `while` loop.

Here's my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int i, j;
        
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        i = sc.nextInt();
        
        j = i - 1;
        
        while(i>0)
        {
            while(j<i)
            {
                System.out.print(" "+i+" ");
                --j;
            }
            System.out.println();
            --i;
        }
    }
}
```

This should be the expected output

[image: expected output]

But when I execute the code, it just keeps typing the number I entered indefinitely.

[image: output]

Comment: Hello and welcome. You forgot to tell us what the problem is. Please [edit] your question to include the expected output and any wrong output or error you're getting instead.

Comment: `while(j<i)` <- if `j` is smaller than `i` once, and you only decrement `j` inside the loop with `--j`, how do you expect `j` to ever become bigger than `i` and your loop to ever end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing \*s as triangles in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047583/printing-s-as-triangles-in-java)

Comment: Lets say i=5. Then j=4. Your while(j<i) loop will run forever. What if you try, "while(j>0)"?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing in an infinite loop because you did "while `j` is less than `i`".
`j` is only being subtracted in that loop, therefore will never be greater than `i` until `j` overflows at `-2147483649`.

I probably would have used `for` loops to code this, but because you used `while`s in the question I will also use them here.

```
//...

//runs the amount of times you input
while(i > 0){
  
  /*
  j is being set to the same value as i, which means the following loop will print out the value of i.
  it will do this j number of times.
  A different variable is used so that we can iterate and count down while still printing the original value of i on that line
  */
  int j = i;
  while(j > 0){
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    j--;
  }
  
  System.out.println(); //goes to the next line after the current one is finished

  i--; //decreases the number being printed for each level in the triangle
}

//...
```